# PHP interactive text form

Tags: php, plugins, generator, live

I am currently designing a site that will have a social plugin/button for itself, like Facebook and Twitter do. My question is: how can i make a text box that when something is entered in it and a button pressed, a field of my social plugin code changed to match the text box? I need it to do the same thing the Facebook's plugin page does, for example the like button needs you to type in the "link" you want the button to like, and then it adds that link in the code and gives the code to you.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript. Take the link inserted, put it in a dynamically generated input field.

Facebook uses iframe BTW.

Comment: Use jquery. look into [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Fetch the url, create a hidden input field, append it to your form.